# Why this jquery selector gives me error? uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ''

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code ti dynamically select attributes of a element but it gives me an error in firebug

**Error:**

> **uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ''**

Here is my code:

```
jQuery('.mydata').click(function(){

    var current_id=jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var current_datatype=jQuery(this).attr('datatype');

    var next_id=parseInt(current_id);

    next_id=next_id+1;

    next_id="'#"+next_id+"'";

    var next_datatype=jQuery(next_id).attr('datatype'); //this line gives error

});
```

Comment: Every answer is correct so which one should i accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you do

`next_id = "#" + next_id;` instead of  `next_id="'#"+next_id+"'";`

Answer (score 4):

when selecting an id you don't need the quotes if you assign it to a variable

change:

```
next_id="'#"+next_id+"'";
var next_datatype=jQuery(next_id).attr('datatype'); //this line gives error
```

into:

```
next_id="#"+next_id;
var next_datatype=jQuery(next_id).attr('datatype'); //this line gives error
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need the extra quotes here

```
next_id="'#"+next_id+"'";
```

should be read

```
next_id="#"+next_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

change this ...

```
next_id="'#"+next_id+"'";
```

to this ...

```
next_id="#"+next_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector becomes something like `'#2'` instead of `#2`. You need to remove the extra '. Also you should never use parseInt without passing in a radix, like `parseInt(currentId, 10)`.